# Azure Websites and Downtime during deployments

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Web Site setup on Azure Web Sites, it's using Reserved mode and has 2 instances.
But when I do an update to my site the site has downtime. 
Is there anyway I can get the deployment to update once instance at a time so that there is no downtime?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question.

Comment: Downtime meaning a delay, or an error?  It should obey the normal overlapped app pool reset semantics of any IIS application, so if your app is reasonably quick to start up from cold, you shouldn't lose any requests.

Comment: downtime as in I try access the website but it does not exist for a few seconds whilst the deployment is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a hot-swappable deployment of new code, you should look to running a WebRole.  WebRole has two environments that can be hot-swapped via CNAME switch.  This allows you to not lose any traffic during downtime.

Azure Websites (being a simpler but less featured offer from Azure) will go down sometime during the upgrade process and come back when the code has been deployed and app recompiled.

Comment: Azure websites now has the concept of swapping deployment slots.